# filename: "error reading characters of string" and "unable to read memory"

Tags: c++, filenames, ifstream

These errors are given when reading a filename from the parameter.

"unable to read memory"
"error reading characters of string"

If the string is defined as a user entered text or as a hardkey then it works fine. But, if a portion of the filename is read from file, concatenated then passed through a parameter, these errors are given.

I tried both with and without `.c_str()`
After removing some stray spaces in the text file, this now works in windows but not in linux?

```
        void batch_helper()
        {

            //batch
            vector <string> field_reports;

            ifstream field_report_batch;
            field_report_batch.open("OCR_batch.txt");
            string line;

            while (true) { //fill stack with batches
                getline(field_report_batch, line);
                if (line.empty() || !field_report_batch || field_report_batch.fail())
                    break;

                field_reports.push_back(line);
            }
            field_report_batch.close();

            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < field_reports.size(); i++) {

                parse_file("timesheets_we" + field_reports[i] + "_batch_export.csv"); //this does not work

                //parse_file("timesheets_we20121221_batch_export.csv"); //this works

            }

        }



        void parse_file(const string timecard_WE)
        {

            //count records
            int timecard_count = 0;
            string line;

            //test input file
            ifstream timecard_test;
            timecard_test.open(timecard_WE.c_str());
            getline(timecard_test, line); //burn header
            while (true){
                getline(timecard_test, line); //read in row_n
                if (!timecard_test || timecard_test.fail()) 
                    break;
                timecard_count++;
            }
            timecard_test.close();
            line.clear();
    }
```

A similar problem posted on stackoverflow is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474038/how-to-read-a-list-of-filenames-from-a-text-file-and-open-them-in-c?rq=1), the issue was hidden white space or stray end of line char. I have checked for white space but so far have not found them.

I will try this:

```
           while (true) {
                if (line.back() == '\r' || line.back() == '\n') {
                    test_log << "pop: " << line.back() << "\r\n";
                    line.pop_back();
                }
            }
```

the resulting out file is

> 20120615
>
> pop:
>
> 20120622
>
> pop:
>
> 20120629
>
> pop:
>
> 20120706
>
> pop:
>
> 20120713
>
> pop:
>
> 20120720
>
> pop:
>
> 20120727
>
> pop:
>
> 20120803
>
> pop:
>
> 20120810
>
> pop:
>
> 20120817
>
> pop:
>
> 20120824
>
> pop:
>
> 20120831
>
> pop:
>
> 20120907
>
> pop:
>
> 20120914
>
> pop:
>
> 20120921
>
> pop:
>
> 20120928
>
> pop:
>
> 20121005
>
> pop:
>
> 20121012
>
> pop:
>
> 20121019
>
> pop:
>
> 20121026
>
> pop:
>
> 20121102
>
> pop:
>
> 20121109
>
> pop:
>
> 20121116
>
> pop:
>
> 20121123
>
> pop:
>
> 20121130
>
> pop:
>
> 20121207
>
> pop:
>
> 20121214
>
> pop:
>
> 20121221
>
> pop:
>
> timesheets_we20120615_batch_export.csv BREAK
>   timesheets_we20120622_batch_export.csv BREAK
>   timesheets_we20120629_batch_export.csv BREAK
>   timesheets_we20120706_batch_export.csv BREAK
>   timesheets_we20120713_batch_export.csv BREAK
>   timesheets_we20120720_batch_export.csv BREAK
>   timesheets_we20120727_batch_export.csv BREAK
>   timesheets_we20120803_batch_export.csv BREAK
>   timesheets_we20120810_batch_export.csv BREAK
>   timesheets_we20120817_batch_export.csv BREAK
>   timesheets_we20120824_batch_export.csv BREAK
>   timesheets_we20120831_batch_export.csv BREAK
>   timesheets_we20120907_batch_export.csv BREAK
>   timesheets_we20120914_batch_export.csv BREAK
>   timesheets_we20120921_batch_export.csv BREAK
>   timesheets_we20120928_batch_export.csv BREAK
>   timesheets_we20121005_batch_export.csv BREAK
>   timesheets_we20121012_batch_export.csv BREAK

The BREAKs in the logfile are endof file breaks.

Comment: yes, I meant to remove 'captricity' and replace it with file

Comment: Try `parse_file(string() + "timesheets_we" + field_reports[i] + "_batch_export.csv");`

Comment: no, that did not work

Comment: You need to provide information about what does not work. Error, message?

Comment: Debugging is easy and fun, give it a try.

Comment: N.m. thank you. Debugging is easy and fun. This is not the time and place to ponder why I get comments like yours occasionally. Possibly, I ma anovice and program as a necessity for my research. But I am not a programmer. But, rest assured. I am debugging to the best of my ability. And, in the past few days have dedicated maybe 12 or more hours to this specific little problem. And then I asked here.

Comment: Neil-Kirk, it is the same two error messages as before. Each timethe filename looks fine as a string, but when the string is used to open the file, when if_error checks are made, it breaks.

Comment: this fixed it  `while (true) { if (line.back() == '\r' || line.back() == '\n') line.pop_back();}` The BREAKs in the logfile are endof file breaks. I have not tried without the `string()` cast prefix, works so I will just leave it. So, what is the logic behing using the string cast as a prefix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is easy and twp part:

PART I:
the text file where I read the partial file names from and then concatenate into a full name, there was a blank space after some of the text. I opened the file, "select all" and then manually removed the trailing blank spaces.

PART II:
this fixed it while (true)

```
{ if (line.back() == '\r' || line.back() == '\n') line.pop_back();}
```

combined solution:

```
while (true) { if (line.back() == '\r' || line.back() == '\n' || line.back() == ' ') line.pop_back();}
```